# How to send a custom message from user application to SYSTEM app?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services, message, createprocess

I have created a windows service to run my custom application with createProcessAsUser. The result is one application running with SYSTEM user in session Id 0 as I expect. My problem is, I need to have some communication between this application an others created by the current user.

If some desktop events happenned (SC_SCREENSAVE, monitor off), events caught by current user apps, I need to tell that to my SYSTEM application. I have used:

SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, CURRENT_USER_HAS_DONE_SOMETHING, 0, 0);

Even the SYSTEM application catch a lot of system events (suspend, logoff...), and is running in the same session Id, my custom messages are never caught. It seems like Sendmessage don't work for SYSTEM user.

How can I send a message from user current session to a SYSTEM application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the old [ControlService function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) along with a user-defined control code. It is not appropriate for complicated communication (you can't pass any parameters to the service) but it works well for the simple "something-happened" notifications you outlined.

Comment: That's it! Control service was exactly what I want. I have openned the service using OpenSCManager with SC_MANAGER_CONNECT acces right, then OpenService with SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL, and a simple call to ControlService solved the problem. It works even the user had no privileges, that's perfect. Thanks a lot @CoreTech.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Windows don't allow exchanging messages between session 0 and desktop sessions. This is called [Session 0 isolation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx).

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2007/02/23/services-isolation-in-session-0-of-windows-vista-and-longhorn-server.aspx).

Usual alternatives are TCP/IP, pipes, remoting, etc, which are described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55639/how-do-you-communicate-between-windows-vista-session-0-and-desktop).

Comment: Thank you very much Zdeslav. I'm going to read your links. When I get a solution I will post again. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously broadcasting messages isn't the correct solution. A nicer solution is probably `CreateEventEx`. This creates a named event. Your regular app can then call `SetEvent` and the `SYSTEM` app can wait on this event.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! I'm gonna work on it right now.